# Flowgear Change default workflow execution time

Tags: flowgear

My problem is when i retrieve too many data from database and select using odbc node

when my workflow is run exception The timeout (30 secs) was exceeded while waiting for a response from DropPoint transactionRequest
    Please help how to resize defalut timelimit of workflow.

Comment: Sharing code always makes it more likely someone will answer.

Comment: This is a no-code scenario; code-sharing isn't applicable.  I don't even think screenshots would add any value.  The question is good as-is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The timeout you mention is the timeout on the connection that is using a DropPoint and not a timeout on the workflow as a whole.

From within the connections pane, open the connection you are using on the workflow and modify the timeout setting there.

Separate to this, if you're calling the workflow via rest api, you can set a timeout. To override the default there, add the query string: _timeout=300 to the url in your consuming app (i.e. Not in the endpoint url setting in Flowgear).

Comment: Hello sir,if it is possible to add custom field in sage evolution sample=>Accounts or Inventory item.

Comment: Rather ask this as a separate question in future but the answer is that User Defined fields are supported on Accounts but not on Inventory Items in the Flowgear Evolution connector. You can see the User Defined fields in the tree presented on the RHS of the property editor when you click "edit xml" against Request Xml on the Sage Evolution connector. Just load the appropriate sample first.